# In Mercurial is there a way to specify a file to only keep the current version of it?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

Basically I only want to keep the file in the repository, but I don't want to trace it in revision history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Mercurial repository does not hold files—not directly, anyway.  A Mercurial repository holds *commits*.  Commits *are* the revision history.  *Commits* hold files, so if the file is going to be in the repository, it is going to be in a commit, and therefore it is in the history.

That's your choice: the file is in the repository by being in commits, and hence is in revision history; or the file is not in the repository.

(Note that you may have files in your *work-tree* that are not in the repository proper.  Such a file is called an *untracked file*.  Since it is not in the repository, cloning the repository does not produce a copy of the untracked file.  This description is a little imprecise, but if you want untracked files, just create them and be happy.  You may want to add such files' names, or regular expression or glob patterns, to a `.hgignore` file that you *do* put in the repository.)